# How to fetch data from webserver using JSON in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json

i want to  fetch data from webserver using JSON and webservice and then parse the JSON Response string.
        then i need to insert the data which i have obtained from the webserver into sqlite database.
        i have done posting the data to server api database through HTTP post method and this is working properly and my data is getting saved to my server database.And the response that i get is in  this format:

```
    {"TokenID":"od28Denamu","isError":false,"ErrorMessage":"","Result":[{"UserId":"153","FirstName":"Rocky","LastName":"Yadav","Email":"rocky@itg.com","ProfileImage":null,"ThumbnailImage":null,"DeviceInfoId":"12"}],"ErrorCode":900}
```

i need to parse json data and save it in my local sqlite database which consist the same database table as of the server database

this is my code :

```
    //this is used to post the data to web server database through HTTP POST method
    -(void)sendRequest
    {
        UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
        NSString *udid = [device uniqueIdentifier];
        NSString *sysname = [device systemName];
        NSString *sysver = [device systemVersion];
        NSString *model = [device model];
        NSLog(@"idis:%@",[device uniqueIdentifier]);
        NSLog(@"system nameis :%@",[device systemName]);
        NSLog(@"System version is:%@",[device systemVersion]);
        NSLog(@"System model is:%@",[device model]);
        NSLog(@"device orientation is:%d",[device orientation]);
        NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Loginkey=%@&Password=%@&DeviceCode=%@&Firmware=%@&IMEI=%@",txtUserName.text,txtPassword.text,model,sysver,udid];
        NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]; 
        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]]; 
        NSLog(@"%@",postLength);
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease]; 
            //this is my web server api method which consist of 5 parameters Loginkey,Password,DeviceCode,Firmware,IMEI
    Loginkey takes Username of user
    Password takes password of user
    DeviceCode takes device model
    Firmware takes device Version
    IMEI takes uniqueidentifier of device.
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.0.68:91/JourneyMapperAPI?RequestType=Login"]]; 
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; 
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"]; 
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"]; 
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];

        NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

        if (theConnection) {
            webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
            NSLog(@"%@",webData);
        }
        else 
        {

        }

    }





    -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response 
    {   
        [webData setLength: 0]; 
    } 

    -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data 
    {         
        [webData appendData:data]; 

    } 

    -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error 
    {     
        [connection release];  
        [webData release]; 

    } 
    //this is used to fetch the data through JSON .
    -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
    {      
        //NSString *loginStatus = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 




        NSString *loginStatus = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:webData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@",loginStatus);
        self.webData = nil;

        NSArray* latestLoans = [(NSDictionary*)[loginStatus JSONValue] objectForKey:@"Login"];
        [loginStatus release];

        //get latest loan
        NSDictionary* loan = [latestLoans objectAtIndex:0];

        //fetch the data
        NSString* fundedAmount = [loan objectForKey:@"Loginkey"];
        NSString* loanAmount = [loan objectForKey:@"Password"];
        NSLog(@"this is foundedamount:%@",fundedAmount);
        NSLog(@"this is loanAmount:%@",loanAmount);

        //float outstandingAmount = [loanAmount floatValue] - [fundedAmount floatValue];

        //NSString* name = [loan objectForKey:@"name"];
        //NSString* country = [(NSDictionary*)[loan objectForKey:@"location"] objectForKey:@"country"];

        //set the text to the label
        //label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Latest loan: %@ from %@ needs another $%.2f, please help",
                      //name,country,outstandingAmount
                     // ];

        //greeting.text = loginStatus;   
        [loginStatus release];           
        [connection release];  
        [webData release]; 
    }
```

But the problem when i fetching the data through JSON code is not working,posting to server is working properly.

When i fetch data `NSLOG(@"this is foundedamount:null")` value is shown .What may be the problem.Please help me in solving this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your problem is to parse a json string, why don't you use a simple json library such as https://github.com/stig/json-framework ?